# Not able to see any statistics like "REGISTERED APPLICATION USERS" in wso2 analytics dashboard

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, dashboard

I am not able to see following statictics like
API USAGE OF APPLICATION
TOP APPLICATION USERS
FAULTY INVOCATIONS PER APPLICATION in Dashboard for APIM Developer statistics.
Only details of "REGISTERED APPLICATION USERS" are shown.
I am using the default H2 database and done "quick setup" of analytics dashboard.
I am using 3.1.0 version for both WSO2 API-M and WSO2 Analytics Dashboard and also enabled the analytics in delployment file in APIM.

Comment: Does the login user have any application registers and API invocation to those applications?

Answer (score 0):

check below pointers

1. is your analytics and APIM 3.1 is under the same folder
2. start components in order analytics worker -> wso2 APIM -> dashboard
3. check that in APIM deployment.toml files analytics is enabled
4. login with the same user in APIM and dashboard